# Dropdown hides behind a div event with a much higher z-index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu that hides behind a div even though I've set for it a much higher z-index here's a screenshot.

[Hidhing menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwKHQ.png)

Comment: We can't debug a screenshot. Reread [ask], and especially [mcve]

Comment: Is the div it's hiding behind also a positioned element?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Yes it has a position of fixed

Comment: Then I'm sorry, but I don't think there's anything else we can do without a code example.

Answer (score 0):

By the amount of information I can collect after seeing that screenshot I can say it is either 1 of the following 2 problems:
1. The parent div of the div with class 'dropdown-menu' do not have "position: relative" property applied to it.
2. Two divs need to be sibling to each other to hide or show one of them behind the other using z-index (they can't have parent child relationship).